# Type checking JavaScript for object properties which change type

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

With this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript
enabled in Settings, there are some objects with valid type changes.

Examples:

```js
let options = {
        logging: false,
    }    
if (process.env.DEBUG_LOG == "true") {
        options.logging = console.log // vscode error: is not assignable to boolean
    }
```

or

```js
 let pgconfig = {
        ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
        max: 5,
    }
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
        //no SSL on localhost
        pgconfig.ssl = false // vscode error
    }
```

These type changes are valid for the functions using them.

How to make vscode understand that both work, without using

```
// @ts-ignore comment on the line before the error:
```

This is a .js file, not .ts. I tried

```js
let options = {
        logging: <any> false,
    } 

or
let options = {
        logging: false as any,
    }
```

but these don't work in JS.

More info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html (not saying how to handle type changes)

Comment: Can you just rename the file to `.ts` so that you can use TypeScript's type annotations to guide the compiler?

Comment: Thanks. I did try, but introduces other errors, eg on `import file from './file.ts'`
I guess `// @ts-ignore` is the only solution for JS in this case?

Comment: Just guessing: maybe you could do `let options = {}; options.logging = false;`? (See [Option literals are open-ended](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#object-literals-are-open-ended).)

Comment: Ah, and in the same section I see that JSDoc is also parsed. So you can use that as a substitute for type annotations as well!

Comment: Both your last options work :) Thanks Thomas! I went with JSDoc. Would  you post these as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [option literals are open-ended](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#object-literals-are-open-ended), you can trick the compiler into deriving an `any` type for a field by assigning to the field after object construction:

```
let options = {};
options.logging = false;
```

An alternative is to use JSDoc to add an [`@type` tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html), which lets you be a bit more strict than the `any` type:

```
/** @type {{logging: (boolean|function(...*))}} */
let options = {
    logging: false,
}
```

(I hope I got that syntax right, but I didn't test it. See also [Types in the Closure Type System](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System).)